# LDAP authentication within Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, ldap

I'm trying to use spring-ldap stuff to protect my application.

This is my WebSecurityConfig file :

```
package mis.maskcenter;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;


@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth

        .ldapAuthentication()
           .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=People")
           .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
           .contextSource()
           .url("ldap://ip_here:389/dc=mycomp,dc=com")
           .managerPassword("managuser")
           .managerDn("uid=managuser");     

    }


}
```

At application startup, the login page replace my home page : good!

Then I try to provide BAD credentials : the page display a BAD CREDENTIAL message : good too :o) there is no message in the application terminal.

Then I try with CORRECT credentials : this time the login page don't display any message, just reload to empty login screen -sic- and in the terminal where I launch the application I have this message :

```
2018-11-16 14:54:54.217 ERROR 22623 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

org.springframework.ldap.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials]; nested exception is javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials]
```

Even after reading ldapAuthentication documentation, my comprehension of the subject is quite limited, so any help would be appreciate :o)

Any suggestion ?
Thanks

Comment: Is your dn pattern complete? Should it be uid={0},ou=People,dc=mycomp,dc=com or something similar?

Comment: I changed to .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=People,dc=mycomp,dc=com") now I have a bad credential message either with correct or not login+passwd but no more problem in the terminal

Comment: I can complete with this piece of code from another application which also connect to LDAP but without Spring stuff `  environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
  environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://ip_here:389");
  environment.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
  environment.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=managuser,dc=mycomp,dc=com");
  environment.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "managuser");
`

Comment: I don't think your manager dn is complete. Do you have the full dn?

Comment: `managerDn` should match `userDnPatterns` so with `{0}` as a placeholder in *'uid={0},ou=People'* either use `managerDn('managuser')` or remove userDnPatterns and pass the full user dn, for example : `managerDn("uid=managuser,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com")`

Comment: @Ryan and @ Eric, I tried with this config :  .ldapAuthentication()
        .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=People")
        .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
        .contextSource()
        .url("ldap://172.16.30.110:389/dc=ipdia,dc=com")
        .managerPassword("proxyuser")
        .managerDn("uid=proxyuser,ou=people,dc=ipdia,dc=com");

Answer (score 0):

I finally get it work by encapsulating the piece of java code that was working into  a custom authentication provider.